# JWT Bearer token authentication fails in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, jwt, authorization

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API application set up with JWT Bearer token authentication, and I'm facing an issue where the token validation fails. I have already tested the token using Postman, and it does not work there either. The problem seems to be on the server-side.

Here's the relevant code for setting up authentication in my Startup.cs:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = jwtAuth.Issuer,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = jwtAuth.Audience,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = jwtAuth.GetSecurityKey(),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        };
    });
```

This is the code for generating the JWT token:

```cs
var authClaims = new List<Claim>
  {
      new (ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName!),
      new (JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
  };

// No role claims are added since I'm not using roles

var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(_jwtConfiguration.GetToken(authClaims));
```

Get token method:

```cs
public JwtSecurityToken GetToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        return new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: Issuer,
            audience: Audience,
            notBefore: DateTime.Now,
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(LifetimeInMinutes)),
            signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(GetSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
    }
```

And here's the secured method with the [Authorize] attribute:

```cs
[HttpPost("/auth/test")]
[Authorize]
public async Task<ActionResult> TestAuthorization()
{
    return Ok();
}
```

When I test this using Postman or my Flutter client, I get the following error:

```
[23:35:31 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://10.0.2.2:5180/auth/test - 0
[23:35:31 INF] Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.
[23:35:31 INF] AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
[23:35:31 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://10.0.2.2:5180/auth/test - 0 - 401 0 - 30.5047ms
```

By the way, here is my Flutter code:

```dart
final url = Uri.parse("${Config.baseUrl}/auth/google");

final Map response = json.decode((await http.post(url, body: {
  'code': signIn?.serverAuthCode,
}))
    .body);

final result = response['result'] as Map;

await http.post(Uri.parse('${Config.baseUrl}/auth/test'), headers: {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Bearer ${result['accessToken']}',
});
```

I tried to use this way generating a token:

```cs
var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(authClaims),
    Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(jwtAuth.GetSecurityKey(), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature),
    Issuer = jwtAuth.Issuer,
    Audience = jwtAuth.Audience,
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
var accessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
```

Comment: `"I'm facing an issue where the token validation fails"`, was the tokon generated? Did you had the change to decode the token if that contains required permission and scope?

Answer (score 3):

I put

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Before

```cs
app.UseAuthorization();
```

And this solved my problem